# Making CLCircularRegion Codable

Tags: swift, codable

I'm trying (in playground) to make CLCircularRegion Codable. But I have an error that I cannot fix: error: initializer requirement 'init(from:)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in the definition of non-final class 'CLCircularRegion'. Any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

// MARK: - CLLocationCoordinate2D

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Codable {

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(longitude)
        try container.encode(latitude)
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let longitude = try container.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self)
        let latitude = try container.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self)
        self.init(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}

// MARK: - CLLocationCoordinate2D

extension CLCircularRegion : Codable {

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(identifier)
        try container.encode(center)
        try container.encode(radius)
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let identifier = try container.decode(String.self)
        let center = try container.decode(CLLocationCoordinate2D.self)
        let radius = try container.decode(CLLocationDistance.self)

        self.init(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)
    }
}

let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 45.123, longitude: 5.678)
let region = CLCircularRegion(center: coordinate, radius: 100, identifier: "identifierTest")

// encode
if let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(region), let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString)

    // decode
    if let decodedRegion = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CLCircularRegion.self, from: jsonData) {
        print(decodedRegion)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to wrap the class in a struct that conforms to Codable

```
struct CodableCircularRegion : Codable {
    var region: CLCircularRegion?
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(region?.identifier)
        try container.encode(region?.center)
        try container.encode(region?.radius)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let identifier = try container.decode(String.self)
        let center = try container.decode(CLLocationCoordinate2D.self)
        let radius = try container.decode(CLLocationDistance.self)

        region = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)
    }

    init(_ region: CLCircularRegion) {
        self.region = region
    }
}
```

The encoding/decoding is almost the same

```
if let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(CodableCircularRegion(region)), let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString)

    // decode
    if let decodedRegion = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CodableCircularRegion.self, from: jsonData) {
        print(decodedRegion.region)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. `CLCircularRegion` is not a `final` class. When you extend a non-final class you can only write `convenience` initializers in the extension. `Decodable` specifies that the initializer must be declared `required`.

But we just saw that you can't do that because Swift doesn't allow you to declare `required` initializers in an extension.

As an aside, in general it's not a good idea to extend somebody else's types to make them conform to `Codable` because at some future point whoever wrote the type might also add `Codable` conformance, and it's very likely that their implementation won't match your implementation, which will cause some bugs that will be very difficult to diagnose.

As mentioned, your best bet is to wrap the `CLCircularRegion` inside a struct that conforms to `Codable`.